# redirect 301 all pages that doesn't exist to a new directory

Tags: redirect

i had build another website in the directory http://www.example.com/newwebsite/
Now all the old pages that doesn't exist on the website i want to redirect them to http://www.example.com/newwebsite/

I have a lot of pages in google webmaster with 404 error , that i want to resolve it. I understand that a 301 redirect will resolve my problem.

Can you help me with the htaccess to redirect the pages that doesn't exist any more?

thank you

Comment: That kind of question has been [asked today](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23326/seo-delete-old-indexed-pages-from-google-301-vs-404#8488991) and migrated to Webmasters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !%{REQUEST_URI} ^/newwebsite/
RewriteRule (.*) /newwebsite/$1 [R=301,L]
```